# Option to rollback using client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes

I would like to rollback the deployment to a particular revision(rollout history) using client-go(6.0.0) library of k8s. I created a deployment using workload API object `apps/v1beta2`. Seems in `apps/v1beta2` there is no `.spec.rollbackTo options`. Where can i find the options to rollback to particular revision using client-go(6.0.0) library. Github Issue https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/398.

Comment: I see, you created an issue in kubernetes/client-go repo. It's better to include the link of the issue too in this description. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/398